# Unable to Sign in iTunes Connect "you must agree terms in iTunes Connect before using this application 2004"

Tags: app-store-connect

I can sign my account in Xcode and [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), but in Connect app installed from App Store cannot.

It prompted me:

**Unable to Sign in iTunes Connect "you must agree terms in iTunes Connect before using this application (2004)"**

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it after one day.

open every item in [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), make sure there is no terms that you should agree.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Open the  [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com"itunesconnect") Link from your Laptop Not Mobile. It will ask you to Accept the Terms and condition.
While you open the link from mobile the Accept option will not visible to you. So open the link from Laptop and Accept the terms and condition.